# Using MATLAB functions in Python for solving a fourth order polynomial

Tags: python, matlab, function

I am solving a fourth order polynomial which has varying coefficients and thus i want to merge a MATLAB function in python.
I am new to this concept and thus i am getting several tracebacks for the test case which i wrote before moving to the actual code.
I am a beginner in both MATLAB and Python.

Here's the python code:

```
import matlab.engine
import math
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
D=(eng.hub(1,0,0,-184602.030,-(75.2)**4))
print(D)
```

Here's the MATLAB code:

```
function D=hub(a,b,c,d,e)
coefvct = [a b c d e];     % Coefficient Vector
D= roots(coefvct)              % Solution
end
```

[Here's the traceback i encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JxiN.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the Matlab engine, but looking at the error, the first thing you need to correct is to give it floats and not interested, since this is what it is complaining about: `eng.hub(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -184602.030,-(75.2)**4))`.

Notice the decimal points in the first three arguments.

Comment: Man it worked. Thanks a lot. Were the decimals a reason of such long tracebacks? Well i guess it's a welcome!